# Which 52 universes from the DC Multiverse survived Crisis on Infinite Earths?

Tags: dc, parallel-universe

In the comic *Crisis on Infinite Earths*, the DC multiverse is destroyed.  But, in *Infinite Crisis* and subsequent comics, it was revealed that the multiverse had been restored/recreated/preserved into 52 other universes, each with their own earth.

Which universes survived as the 52? For example, Earth-3 housed the Crime Syndicate, and this universe was (presumably) destroyed in *Crisis on Infinite Earths*; does it still exist as one of the 52 earths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DC_Multiverse_worlds).  It lists all worlds in the DC Multiverse for the original (pre-crisis) multiverse, the 52 multiverse, and the New 52 multiverse.  A description is also given highlighting the inhabitants and other defining characteristics of each world.